# How to sum up td value having same class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
<tr role="row" class="odd">
   <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">0 PCS</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
   <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">500 PCS</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">     
   <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">600 PCS</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
</tr>
```

Here i want to add value of td having same class using jquery .
I tried it using forloop and hasclass its not working.
Here class name is open

how can I solve it?

Comment: Which class you are targettting ?

Comment: open class .....

Comment: Could you please try the given answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Below should do

```
var total =0;
$("td.open").each(function(){
   total += parseInt($(this).text());
})
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.each`

As per suggestion by user9263373, using `parseFloat` to parse the text for decimal values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var total = 0

  $(".open").each(function() {
    var text = parseFloat($(this).text());
    total += text;
  });

  console.log("Total is " + total);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">

    <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">0 PCS</td>
    <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
    <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>

  </tr>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">

    <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">500 PCS</td>
    <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
    <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">

    <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">600 PCS</td>
    <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
    <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var sum = 0;
$('tr td.open').each(function(){
  sum += parseInt($(this).text());
});
console.log('Total: ' + sum + ' PCS');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">

   <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">0 PCS</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>

</tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">

   <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">500 PCS</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
      </tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">

   <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">600 PCS</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `.open` class and parse the integer value to get the total:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('.open').each(function(index){
    var value = $(this).text().split(' ')[0];
    var parsedValue = parseInt(value);
    sum += parsedValue;
  });
  
  console.log('Total PCS: '+ sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
<tr role="row" class="odd">

   <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">0 PCS</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>

</tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">

   <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">500 PCS</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
      </tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">

   <td class=" stock-log-opening open ">600 PCS</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>
   <td class=" stock-log-opening"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 0.00</td>

</tr>
</table>
```